# invisible layer over blog page with a link

Tags: html, hyperlink, blogs

I want to create transparent layer with url link when clicked anywhere on page must open the link in new window. and on single click the transparent layer must close and then come again after a time interval.and I want this to be done in my Blog.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please read [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery and try steps below:

1. on ready function of jquery, put the clicking overlay element (say its id: elementontop) over the entire page with a z-index higher,
2. grab click event of overlayed layer (i.e. #elementontop) and do following -

   - Hide overlaying element
   - Determine cursor coordinates
   - Get element on those coordinates
   - Trigger click on that element

to execute #2 you may get hint from following code -

```
$('#elementontop).click(function (e) {
    $('#elementontop).hide();
    $(document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY)).trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: but is it possible to use jquery in blogger?
next is how to add timer

Comment: in general every blogging platform come with jQuery. you were asking that you want to do it in your blog. so, if you host your own blogging platform its easy to get jquery.